# How can I make a field visible in Rally App builder

Tags: rally

I have a Rally grid that I'm creating using the Rally app builder. Standard grid using the defect model. One of the fields in the defect model is set to hidden in the field setup in the Rally Workspaces and Projects setup. I'd like to dynamically make the field visible in my grid so that it only appears on my grid and not on the defect page when entering a defect. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was a pretty tricky one.  The grid and board components are hard wired to not show data from hidden fields by default and unfortunately there are not any config properties exposed to turn this behavior off.  Here's what I came up with:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    columnCfgs: [
        'FormattedID',
        'Name',
        'Owner',
        {
          text: 'Hidden Field', //set column header text
          renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
            //return the rendered field data
            return record.get('c_HiddenField');
          }
        }
    ],
    context: this.getContext(),
    storeConfig: {
        model: 'userstory',
        fetch: ['c_HiddenField'] //need to explicitly fetch
    }
});
```

Basically you include a column in your columnCfgs without a dataIndex specified.  Set the text and renderer to work with your field.
You'll also need to manually fetch your field in the storeConfig since the grid won't understand how to do it otherwise.